# Custom label offsets for data points

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data point file like this

```
"abcd"   0.3   0.7
"efgh"   0.4   0.2
```

I want to create a x-y chart and put "abcd" and "efgh" with custom offsets. The following command

```
plot "data.txt"  using 2:3:1 with labels point pt 7 offset 1,1
```

sets the offset for all labels, so some labels may overlap each other. I want to put the first one on "offset 1,1" and put the second one on "offset 2,0"

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is 4 years old, it shouldn't be unanswered. If every label needs an individual offset and if the offsets cannot be calculated by some formula depending on the textlength or other parameters, you have to store these individual offsets somewhere.
For example as extra columns in the datafile (or maybe a separate datafile).
Then plot your data with points and plot again the labels including the individual offsets.

Data:

```
# label   x     y  xoff yoff
"abcd"   0.3   0.7   1   1
"efgh"   0.4   0.2   2   0
```

Code:

```
plot "data.txt" using 2:3 with points pt 7 title "Datapoints",\
    '' using ($2+$4):($3+$5):1 with labels notitle
```